# Question on Jech's introduction to Iterated Forcing (What really is $P\ast Q$?)

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Jech's introduction to iterated forcing is really confusing me. He starts with two-step forcing, but to be honest, even on the first page of Chapter 16, the first definition where he defines $P\ast Q$  I am confused. I'm really not able to move forward until I understand this definition. Can someone break this definition down a little bit for me?

Here's the definition of $P\ast \dot{Q}$ that Jech provides:

$P\ast\dot{Q} = \{ (p,\dot{q}):p\in P\; \text{and}\; \Vdash_P\dot{q}\in\dot{Q}\}$

$(p_1,\dot{q_1})\leq (p_2,\dot{q_2})$ iff $p_1\leq p_2$  and $p_1\Vdash\dot{q_1}\leq \dot{q_2}$

This vaguely looks like product forcing, but I really think it's just the $\Vdash_{P}$ notation, various dots, and really just not knowing what it *is* isn't helping. Jech explains the $\Vdash_P$ notation, but that isn't really helping.

Comment: The asterisk is \ast in latex. It would be better if your question included the definition that's giving you troubles and what precisely you don't understand, so that we can answer without having access to a copy of Jech

Comment: I've edited the question @AlessandroCodenotti

Comment: It is kind of like a product, except that until you force with $P$ there is no $Q$ to take the product with, so instead of looking at pairs (p,q) you look at pairs (p, name for a set that p forces to be in Q) (tangential but doesn't Jech's definition run into size issues?)

Comment: I'm going to have to think about what you said a little bit more. And I'm not sure what you mean by "size issues." So $P\ast Q$ is the forcing notion where we first force with $P$, where no $Q$ can be considered, and then afterwards, once $P$ forces all of $Q$, we force $Q$? Maybe I'm getting it a bit mixed up.

Comment: Yes, start in a ground model $M$. Forcing with $P\ast \dot Q$ over $M$ is the same as forcing with $P$ over $M$ thus obtaining $M[G]$ and then forcing over $M[G]$ with $\dot{Q}^G$. The point of the $P\ast\dot Q$ poset is that this two step forcing can all be described in $M$

Comment: This will also be a suitable place to tell you that you should just work with the definition for a while. Not understanding it can help you in that it forces you to work slowly and carefully. And to quote John von Neuman, *"Young man, in mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them”*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me try and give an example that might help and clarify. Consider the following scenario. We start with a model of $\sf GCH$, say $L$ for good measure, now we want to violate $\sf GCH$ on some of the $\aleph_n$s. This essentially defines a real number, but you want to be clever, and not use any of the real numbers already in the ground model.

So, as a start you're adding a Cohen real, $c\subseteq\omega$, then you force with $\prod_{n\in c}\operatorname{Add}(\omega_n,\omega_{n+2})$ to violate $\sf GCH$ exactly on those $\aleph_n$s whose index was in the Cohen real.

How would you describe this whole construction from $L$, then? There is no "obvious" partial order. But the Cohen forcing has an obvious partial order, and once the Cohen real was added, the next step also has an obvious partial order.

Now, that second step has a name, since it lives in $L[c]$, and so we can use that name and combine it with the Cohen forcing to create what is the iteration forcing in one go.

So, how would that work? Well, as we "progress" further along the Cohen real, we learn more, for example, will $59$ be in the Cohen real? We don't know at first, but then we do. Once a condition decided that, we know that our next forcing will have a factor of the form $\operatorname{Add}(\omega_{59},\omega_{61})$. This helps to "reveal" the second step one bit at a time.

Comment: I have never seen this $\text{Add}(\alpha,\beta)$ notation before. Could you clarify before I read on?

Comment: That is the forcing to add $\beta$ new subsets to $\alpha$. The conditions are partial functions $p\colon\beta\times\alpha\to2$ with $|p|<|\alpha|$; the order is reverse inclusion.

Comment: Yeah, it's starting to click a little more. I think as I start to work in Chapter 16 more, it'll come into place. The comment you posted above with the von Neuman quote is great.